# Function definition has type error in function many

Tags: haskell

I recently started learning Haskell and I am currently working through the "Higher Order Functions for Parsing" paper. You can find it [Here.](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/parsing.pdf)

The paper defines a function called `many`.

```
many :: parser * ** -> parser * [**]
many p = ((p $then many p) $using cons) $alt (succeed [])
```

I am trying to convert it to Haskell.

```
succeed v inp = [(v, inp)]

fail' inp = []

satisfy p [] = fail' []
satisfy p (x:xs)
  | p x = succeed x xs
  | otherwise = fail' xs

literal x = satisfy (==x)

alt' p1 p2 = \inp -> p1 inp ++ p2 inp

then' p1 p2 = \inp -> [((v1, v2), out2) | (v1, out1) <- p1 inp, (v2, out2) <- p2 out1]

using' p f = \inp -> [(f v, out) | (v, out) <- p inp]

many' p = ((p `then'` (many' p)) `using'` (:)) `alt'` (succeed [])
```

I have tested all the pieces in isolation and they work fine. But the definition  of many is giving me error. I can't seem to figure out what is the issue. I am doing exactly how it's mentioned in the paper.

```
Main.hs:19:56: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘[(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]’
      Expected type: t -> [([(a, b)] -> [(a, b)], t)]
        Actual type: t -> [([a0], t)]
    • In the second argument of ‘alt'’, namely ‘(succeed [])’
      In the expression:
        ((p `then'` (many' p)) `using'` (:)) `alt'` (succeed [])
      In an equation for ‘many'’:
          many' p = ((p `then'` (many' p)) `using'` (:)) `alt'` (succeed [])
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: t -> [(a, t)] (bound at Stum.hs:19:7)
        many' :: (t -> [(a, t)]) -> t -> [(b, t)] (bound at Stum.hs:19:1)
   |
19 | many' p = ((p `then'` (many' p)) `using'` (:)) `alt'` (succeed [])
   | 
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude>
```

Comment: In the future, please do not include images of text (code, error messages, etc.) unless the question specifically relates to text color, font, etc. Images of text are not accessible to visually impaired people and impede searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a lot easier to follow if you had types on all your top-level definitions.

Regardless, I think the problem is in the interaction between `using'` and currying. I note that `then'` parses two values into a pair, and the sample code you're following parses applies `cons` to that pair to create a list from the pair elements as the head and tail of the list. But `(:)` is curried - if you apply it to a pair, the pair is just the head of the list, and it still expects a second argument for the tail. You should decide whether you want `using'` to take a curried function or not.  If you want to stick as close to the paper you're following as possible, you'll leave the definition of `using'`, but change `many'` to

```
many' p = ((p `then'` (many' p)) `using'` uncurry (:)) `alt'` (succeed [])
```

`uncurry` is a simple helper function exposed by `Prelude` that just happens to solve exactly this issue.

Note: all this is unchecked. It's the best quick guess I can provide without seeing the types involved.

Here's a bit more explanation to try to make this more understandable:

`(:)` has the type `a -> [a] -> [a]`. `uncurry (:)` (or equivalently, `(\(h, t) -> h:t)`, in case `uncurry` is a bit much to wrap your head around at once) has the type `(a, [a]) -> [a]`. That difference should be what you keep in mind as you work through the rest.

Note that `then'` tuples up the parsed values in `((v1, v2), out2)`.  Note that `using'` transforms the parsed value as a whole in `(f v, out)`.  When those get chained together, it ends up evaluating an expression along the lines of `f (v1, v2)`. Given how `many'` will use `then'`, `v1` is going to be a single parse result, and `v2` will be a list of subsequent parse results. You want to combine those together into a bigger list, `(v1:v2)`. You need to do that by applying some function `f` to `(v1, v2)`. Now go back to the difference between `(:)` and `uncurry (:)`. Only one of those will have the right type to do that when provided as `f`.

I hope this expanded explanation makes it a bit easier to see what's going on.

Comment: OMG this so worked. I still don't understand precisely what happened. I need to read your answer again tomorrow. My head is not able to understand what you did